# Script/Commands that can read system drivers and OS platform details

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file, dos

This might be a very broad question so I apologize in advance.
I am looking for a scipt/command that can extract OS platform data of my current system. I want it to give me such details:

Graphics driver 
Network Driver
OS version
BT driver 
Audio driver

and so on...you get the point.

Does anyone know of anyway I can achieve this....I need to be able to read it using a windows command.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't see why you need a script when Windows has a built in tool called **System Information** you can use to get all the information about your hardware. If you insist, you can do a bit more research on how to use **WMI** to gather the needed information. You are better off doing the research your self so you learn better

Comment: Type this at a command prompt `WMIC /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment above its best to have a look arround at the WMI objects powershell provide.
Try a few queries to get used to the syntax and then you can start formating the output for your needs, Get-WMIObject has many classes with different properties - example below...

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -computername "computername"
```

Above will filter out properties such as Domain, Manufacturer, model, name, Pysical Memory. You can also use:

```
| select-object name, .....
```

To filter specifc information. Below has some useful information

http://www.petri.co.il/get-wmiobject-wmi-powershell-tricks.htm

Answer (score 0):

[image]Goto command prompt and type `msinfo32 /report D:\result.txt` the system info will be save in D:\result.txt file if you want it to be a script write this in notepad and save it as a `.bat` file and run it